# File is not retrieved and saved correctly ( only 2 lines of code )

Tags: php, image, file-get-contents

I've isolated a bug to 2 lines of code:

```
    $file = @file_get_contents( "http://d36xtkk24g8jdx.cloudfront.net/bluebar/e2609e5/images/ico/favicon.ico" );

    // echo $file;  // verfied file is populated 

    echo file_put_contents("../favicons/" . "instagram_com.ico", $file); // verifed bytes saved
```

What I'm finding is that the when the contents are viewed in the browser there is actual data.

Look the output of above [HERE](http://arcmarks.com/arcmarks/source/class.TestFunction.php?a=a&b=b&c=foo) if you like.

However the file that is saved does not appear to be a .ico on my client or server.

Despite the correct file extension, SO will not let me upload it, as it is correctly detected as not an image file.

The correct file is easily obtained by pasting the link into the url of the the browser.

http://d36xtkk24g8jdx.cloudfront.net/bluebar/e2609e5/images/ico/favicon.ico

and just using `save as` to download it.

However, I need the automated version working and don't know how to troubleshoot this further.

I verified that `file_get_contents` does get content and that `file_put_contents` actually saves the content.

However, it is not a valid image file.

Comment: done any comparisons between what your browser is fetching v.s. what php is fetching? any byte differences? different content? Remember that just because the url is the same in both instances doesn't mean that the server will send the same content to both.

Comment: 5.4K and 4.3K so it appears to be different data ... this method has worked the first 90 or so times on different domains and this is the first domain that has this problem.

Comment: check that your browser isn't silently saving it as something else, like a .bmp. IE is notorious for silently trashing data like that because it thinks it's smarter than you.

Comment: it's easy to look at the data `file_get_contents()` returns using the link I provided above.  Is there a way to validate it or determine what the issue is.  I can't even open that file in an image editor like inkscape.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the header you could obtain from the image displayed in the browser, you will notice the following important "fact":

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Content-Type: image/x-icon 
Content-Length: 4397 
Connection: keep-alive 
Date: Mon, 06 Oct 2014 23:36:51 GMT 

Content-Encoding: gzip

Expires: Sun, 17-Jan-2038 19:14:07 GMT 
Last-Modified: Mon, 06 Oct 2014 23:35:34 GMT 
...
```

Meaning: it's not a regular icon, it's gzipped. So, when you try to download it using `file_get_contents` you will receive some string which is NOT an icon. (Browsers support gzipped files out of the box, cause its
often used to compress data)

You can use the following method to download a gziped file and store it as a "plain-file":

```
function download_content_gzip($url, $out){
  //fetch compressed file
  $tmp = file_get_contents($url);
  file_put_contents("tmp.gzip", $tmp);

  $buffer_size = 4096; // read 4kb at a time

  // Open files (in binary mode)
  $file = gzopen("tmp.gzip", 'rb');
  $out_file = fopen($out, 'wb');

  while(!gzeof($file)) {
     fwrite($out_file, gzread($file, $buffer_size));
  }

  // close
  fclose($out_file);
  gzclose($file);
}
```

This can be optimized to avoid the temp-filename but that's your homework :-)

usage:

```
download_content_gzip("http://d36xtkk24g8jdx.cloudfront.net/bluebar/e2609e5/images/ico/favicon.ico", "instagram.ico");
```

Finally your "instagram.ico" will be a valid file.

Note: `gzopen()` can read uncompressed files as well. So if you have multiple sources and don't want to determine the actual content-Type, this method would work for both cases.

---

For PHP > 5.4 it can be written in a few lines:

```
$content = file_get_contents_gzip("http://d36xtkk24g8jdx.cloudfront.net/bluebar/e2609e5/images/ico/favicon.ico");
file_put_contents("result.ico", $content);

function file_get_contents_gzip($url){
   return gzdecode(file_get_contents($url));
}
```

---

For older PHP Versions > 4.0.1 there *should* be *gcuncompress()* for strings - but it seems to fail.

This little workaround worked so far:

```
$content = file_get_contents_gzip("http://d36xtkk24g8jdx.cloudfront.net/bluebar/e2609e5/images/ico/favicon.ico");
file_put_contents("result.ico", $content);

function file_get_contents_gzip($url){
   return gzdecode(file_get_contents($url));
}

function gzdecode($string) { // no support for 2nd argument
   return file_get_contents('compress.zlib://data:who/cares;base64,'. base64_encode($string));
}
```